# Optimize MySQL range query with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the temperature for each day (huge table) and a table with period start and end dates (small table). Now I want to know the average temperature for each period, but the query takes a long time. Can it be improved?

**NOTE:** the long response times dissappear after upgrading to version 5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2, and may be caused by a bug in MySQL versions prior to 5.6.8 (see comment by Quassnoi)

To rebuild the day and period tables with random data:

```
create table days (
  day int not null auto_increment primary key,
  temperature float not null);

insert into days values(null,rand()),(null,rand()),
  (null,rand()),(null,rand()),(null,rand()),(null,rand()),
  (null,rand()),(null,rand()); # 8 rows

insert into days select null, d1.temperature
  from days d1, days d2, days d3, days d4,
  days d5, days d6, days d7; # 2M rows

create table periods(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  first int not null,
  last int not null,
  index(first) using btree,
  index(last) using btree,
  index(first,last) using btree);

# add 10 periods of 1-11 days each
insert into periods(first,last)
  select floor(rand(day)*2000000), floor(rand(day)*2000000 + rand()*10)
  from days limit 10;
```

Listing all day temperatures for each periods is no problem (returns in 1ms):

```
select id, temperature
  from periods join days on day >= first and day <= last;
```

Now, with GROUP BY, it is actually quite slow (~1750ms)

```
# ALT1
select id, avg(temperature)
  from periods join days on day >= first and day <= last group by id;
```

Replacing the <= and >= with BETWEEN speeds it up slightly (~1600ms):

```
# ALT2
select id, avg(temperature)
  from periods join days on day between first and last group by id;
```

It turns out that results for a single period are returned immediately (1ms):

```
select id, (select avg(temperature)
  from days where day >= first and day <= last) from periods
  where id=1;
```

However, without the WHERE, it takes as much as 4200 ms, which averages to 420 ms per period!

```
# ALT3
select id,
  (select avg(temperature) from days where day >= first and day <= last)
  from periods;
```

What makes the queries so slow -- even (a lot) more than 10 times slower than getting results for a single period, although the **periods** table has only 10 rows? Is there any way to optimize this query?

**EDIT:** some more info:

```
mysql> select @@version;
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
+-------------------------+

# ALT1
mysql> explain select id, avg(temperature) from periods join days on day >= first and day <= last group by id;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | periods | index | first,last,first_2 | first_2 | 8       | NULL |      10 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | days    | ALL   | PRIMARY            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2097596 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+

# ALT1 without GROUP BY
mysql> explain select id, temperature from periods join days on day >= first and day <= last;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | periods | index | first,last,first_2 | first_2 | 8       | NULL |      10 | Using index                                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | days    | ALL   | PRIMARY            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2097596 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+

# ALT2
mysql> explain select id, avg(temperature) from periods join days on day between first and last group by id;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | periods | index | first,last,first_2 | first_2 | 8       | NULL |      10 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | days    | ALL   | PRIMARY            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2097596 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+

# ALT3
mysql> explain select id, (select avg(temperature) from days where day >= first and day <= last) from periods;
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | periods | index | NULL          | first_2 | 8       | NULL |      10 | Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | days    | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2097596 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+

# ALT3 with where
mysql> explain select id, (select avg(temperature) from days where day >= first and day <= last) from periods where id = 1;
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | periods | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |             |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | days    | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL  |   10 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

**EDIT2:** execution plan for nested query in FROM, as suggested by Lennart (query execution time 3ms)

```
mysql> explain select id,avg(temperature) from (select id,temperature from periods join days on day between first and last) as t group by id;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |       50 | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | periods    | index | first,last,first_2 | first_2 | 8       | NULL |       10 | Using index                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | days       | range | PRIMARY,day        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |        5 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x3) |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+--------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please use EXPLAIN on your queries and show the results.

Comment: Very nice question, working queries to reproduce the problem. All do as wau does!

Comment: Maybe increase the join buffer?

Comment: The sizes of the periods can vary considerably, given how you create them.  I suspect that if you look at the numbers of days being processed, you'll understand why `id = 1` is faster than other ids.

Comment: @wau: which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: sizes of the periods are 0 to 9 days. This is a bug in MySQL: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41659

Comment: @Quassnoi, thanks, upgrade to a more recent version (5.6.19-1~exp1ubuntu2) does the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one ugly trick, since:

```
select id, temperature 
from periods join days 
    on day between first and last;
```

is fast, we could try to provoke the optimizer to evaluate this first. Using a sub-query alone is not sufficient:

```
select id, avg(temperature) 
from (
    select id, temperature 
    from periods 
    join days 
        on day between first and last
) as t 
group by id;
[...]
10 rows in set (1.67 sec)
```

However, calling a non deterministic function in the sub-query seems to do the trick:

```
select id, avg(temperature) 
from (
    select id, temperature, rand() 
    from periods 
    join days 
        on day between first and last
) as t 
group by id;
[...]
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Unless critical and necessary I would stay away from such tricks. As the optimizer gets better (maybe next fix) it might skip the call to rand(), all the sudden your old plan and performance is back in business.

If you you do use such tricks, make sure to document them carefully in the code so you can clean them up when they are no longer necessary.

```
MariaDB [test]> select @@version;
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 10.0.20-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

explain select id, avg(temperature) from periods join days on day between first and last group by id;
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                           |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | periods | index | first,last,first_2 | first_2 | 8       | NULL |      10 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | days    | ALL   | PRIMARY            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2094315 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |

explain select id, avg(temperature) from (select id, temperature from periods join days on day between first and last) as t group by id;
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | extra                                           |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | periods | index | first,last,first_2 | first_2 | 8       | NULL |      10 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort    |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | days    | ALL   | PRIMARY            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2094315 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |


explain select id, avg(temperature) from (select id, temperature, rand() from periods join days on day between first and last) as t group by id;
| id   | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                          |
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |       2 | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|    2 | DERIVED     | periods    | index | first,last,first_2 | first_2 | 8       | NULL |      10 | Using index                                    |
|    2 | DERIVED     | days       | ALL   | PRIMARY            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 2094315 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
```

Comment: thanks, this works for me -- actually even without the RAND() this query is fast

Comment: For me at takes about the same time as the first with the sample data. I added the plan I got without rand(). I noticed that we use different versions, perhaps that can explain the different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a compound covering index on `days (day,temperature)`. It should crank up your speed a bit.

Comment: A two-field `InnoDB` table with `day` as a primary key is already such a compound index.

Comment: @Quassnoi Can you give a reference for that?

Comment: @Quassnoi I do not read anything on this page, which supports your assumption? Closest is `In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row`, but here is no secondary index. I am asking, because I see InnoDB prefer the compound index as soon as it exists. And without it's performing a full table scan. This challenges your statement.

Comment: @GhostGambler: this is not an assumption, this is how InnoDB works. *When you define a PRIMARY KEY on your table, InnoDB uses it as the clustered index*

Comment: @Yes, but there is nothing in the clustered index besides the PK. Whereas in a compound index all values are taken into account.

Comment: @GhostGambler: do you know what a clustered index is? There is everything in the clustered index besides the PK.

Comment: With the compound index, I do not notice any change in response time.